# How to evaluate the sum of list only for few elements

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have list and k = 8 (maximum sum). I want to add those elements of list whose total sum is equal or smaller than k = 8  and I want the number of elements only whom I have added.

What I have tried:

```
lst = [1,2,3,4,7,9,12]
final = []
sum = 0
for i in range(len(lst)):
    if sum < 8:
        sum = sum +i
        final.append(i)
print(final)
```

The list is sorted. it may be unsorted by user input. First I will sort the list. Then I will check the condition and adding one by one and append only those elements.

As this code doesn't give correct output as I want, what should I do?

Comment: THe ```for i in range()``` <br />
gives only the index of the elements in array.
<br/>
You need to access the elements of the array. So, There is 2 ways to do that. <br/>
1)
```
for i in range(len(arr)):
    arr[i]
```

or <br />
2)
```
for i in arr:
   print(i)
```
where the above loop can be used to access the elements in the array.

Comment: Avoid using ```sum``` as a variable name. ```sum``` is a keyword in Python.

Comment: @Ram It is the name of a built-in function, but not a keyword. If it was a keyword then it would be a syntax error to *try* to assign to it.

Comment: @kaya3 True. It's a built-in funciton.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I have understood from your question.

> You are given a list of elements (not necessarily sorted) and a value `k`. You must return the items of list whose sum is less than or equal to `k`.

Here is the code

```
lst = [1,2,3,4,7,9,12]
lst.sort()
final = []
sums = 0
k = 10
for i in lst:
    if sums + i <= k:
        sums = sums + i
        final.append(i)
print(final)
```

```
# Output

final = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

as Aravind said.the `i` is index not value

```py
lst = [1,2,3,4,7,9,12]
final = []
sum = 0
for item in lst:
    if sum < 8:
        sum = sum +item
        final.append(item)
print(final)
```

and according to Ram.you should not use `sum` as a variable.is a keyword in python.